# How to get Custom Object with related Item__Feed in SOQL

Tags: soql, query, feeditem

If it's possible to write SOQL query to get object i.e. 'Test__c' with his ItemFeed 'Test__Feed' ?

--EdIt

I want to make something like this:

```
 SELECT Body, (SELECT Name, Id from Test__c) FROM Test__Feed WHERE ParentId IN Test__c.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// My solution
It is possible. Example

```
Select Id, Name, Something__c, (Select Body From Feeds) From Test__c
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58132)

Comment: I don't understand? I answered myself to this question before Sakthivel N do that.

Comment: Then add an explanation of the answer - just posting the code is not very clear on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Body from Test__Feed //Relationship name) FROM Test__c
```

Comment: Didn't understand relationship ... in FROM part of query call

Comment: This is a inner query where getting related child records and its parent in single query

Comment: this is correctSelect Id, Name, Something__c, (Select Body From Feeds) From Test__c

Comment: but Feeds should be child of Test__c

Comment: Yea. I write that in my response. Thank's for the help. +1

Comment: @SakthivelN Please move the explanation into the answer from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In the background, once an object is enable for feed tracking, Salesforce will create new object end with suffix Feed (for Standard object) or __Feed (for Custom object). This is available in API version 18.0 and later.

Using SOQL, you can do this query:

```
Select Id,
  Body,
  Parent.Name,
  ParentId
From Test__Feed
```

This query will return all feeds tag to Test__c object only.

Comment: Yea, I understand that. However, I would build something like this solution (pseudocode) SELECT Body, (SELECT Name, Id from Test__c) FROM Test__Feed WHERE ParentId IN Test__c.Id

Comment: ParentId and Parent.Name will give you the information you are looking for from your custom object.

Comment: OK but I would also like to show custom fields.

Comment: At this point in time I am not aware of SF supporting relationship queries on Chatter Feed Item.